# Jquery animate duration: movement not smooth enought

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, smoothing

This is the firt time that I'm writing here. I have some problems with the JQuery animate: when the duration is really slow (for example, 10000) the movements are not smooth enought. I need a "natural" movement for my div. Does someone know a solution for my problem? Or could you advice me about what to do? Thanks!!!!
The code is something like this:

```
function moveFoo(){
    var timeFoo = setInterval(function(){
        var $foo = $("#foo");
        $foo.animate({"top": "-=10px"}, 20000, "linear");
        $foo.animate({"top": "+=10px"}, 20000, "linear");
    }, 1);
};
moveFoo();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into requestanimationframe and/or use a tweening engine that uses requestanimationframe. Timer based animations like those used in the jQuery tweening engine are not efficient and timers lead to inconsistent animation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: thank you! I didn't know anything about that. I've been reading about requestAnimationFrame, and I've just tryed to make it work. However the animation isn't smoother. I'm testing it on Chrome:     window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(foo);  Any idea?